# Read and display SQL table from network on Android application using SQLite

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, networking

Good evening

As part of a major project for my studies, I am trying to create a system in which an android application can pull a table from an SQL2008 database on the university network and display it in a listview. While I have managed to achieve for different projects this using SQLite tables stored on the device locally, I am having trouble trying to find a way to get the table from a network location, if possible. If possible I would like to avoid having to save any tables or information locally.

The intention once the data is pulled and displayed is to be able to edit and update records on the mobile device before returning the data to the database, again something I know the general process of but am unable to do so without the data to test with.

So in short, is it possible to get records from a table on a network location using an android device without saving it locally to the device? If so what methods should I be looking into?

Comment: I get that the two are not the same thing, the intention is just to use SQLite features on the mobile application to manage one of the tables within the database, which if my knowledge serves me should be possible. I am not intending to use an android device to host or create an SQL server, that has already been done elsewhere

Comment: In order to retrieve data from SQL Server, you'll have to connect to SQL Server from the Android side. So start with a search for *connect to SQL Server from Android*.